# Quelles seraient d’autres façons (courantes ou familières) de dire : « Il lui fait constamment honte de son oisiveté »?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Contexte: L’ami de Jean-Claude n’a pas de travail.

> En soirée, Jean-Claude fait constamment honte à son meilleur ami de son oisiveté.

D’autres idées qui me viennent en tête.

> En soirée, Jean-Claude jette l’opprobre sur son meilleur ami en faisant sans cesse référence à son inoccupation.

> En soirée, Jean-Claude couvre son meilleur ami d’humiliation en faisant constamment allusion à son inactivité.

> En soirée, Jean-Claude fait affront à son meilleur ami en évoquant sans cesse sa précarité.

> En soirée, Jean-Claude revient toujours sur le désoeuvrement de son meilleur ami pour le déprécier dans l’esprit d’autrui.

> En soirée, Jean-Claude se sert de l’inactivité de son meilleur ami pour lui faire honte et le descendre aux yeux de tous.

Comment: "faire honte à x de son inactivité"  me semble un peu boiteux. gêner n'est pas un verbe plus adapté? causer une gêne à son ami? Il le gêne constamment en évoquant ou faisant allusion à son inactivité.

Comment: @Lambie Votre idée est bonne, mais je ne pense pas que la tournure que j’ai présentée en titre soit boiteuse car elle est répertoriée dans le CNRTL: -faire honte à qqn (de qqc.) Faites lui honte de sa paresse (Ac. 1835-1935).

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/honte

Comment: Mais bon, je suis d’accord sur le fait qu’il ne s’agit peut-être pas du terme le plus approprié ici, « gêner » conviendrait mieux si l’on s’en rapporte au contexte qui concerne la relation entre deux amis, en ce sens que de véritables amis ne feraient pas en sorte de s’humilier l’un l’autre.

Comment: Si c’était vraiment le cas, il serait préférable, dans leur intérêt propre, de mettre fin à cette relation toxique, à moins bien sûr que chacun d’eux y trouve une certaine complaisance, ce que je doute fort.

Comment: Oui, mais c'est vraiment littéraire. Pas du tout familier comme vous avez mis dans la question.

Comment: Tournure plus familière: Jean-Claude gêne tout le temps son meilleur ami devant autrui parce qu’il n’a pas d’emploi, il prend un malin plaisir à souligner cette information à la grande honte de ce dernier.

Comment: Thérèse, on ne va pas écrire le bouquin à votre place tout de même. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

À mon avis, de manière usuelle, c'est plutôt Jean-Claude qui se comporte comme si son ami lui faisait honte, mais la formulation en question est [possible](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/honte/40358#162811), dans le sens de *faire des reproches*. On peut formuler un peu différemment avec « Jean-Claude reproche constamment à son ami d'être sans emploi en public. ». On peut aussi penser à *dénigrer*, *rabaisser* ici : « Jean-Claude rabaisse constamment son ami parce qu'il est sans emploi ». Voire les deux formulations ensemble « Jean-Claude reproche constamment à son ami d'être sans emploi et en profite pour le dénigrer devant tout le monde » ; on peut employer une locution avec un participe présent pour expliquer comment se réalise l'action du verbe conjugué : « Jean-Claude rabaisse son ami devant tout le monde en lui reprochant d'être sans emploi/inactif. ».